# Makefile pass arguments to a C program

Tags: makefile

I have google but it seems to not be possible, is there a way to have the run command in a makefile be able to pass any arguments given down to the program simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
argset1:
    ./a.out arg1 arg2

argset2:
    ./a.out arg3 arg4

arg1='default1'
arg2='default2'
custom:
    ./a.out $(arg1) $(arg2)
```

You can do:

```
make argset1
make argset2
make custom arg1=1234 arg2=3321
```

Comment: But is there any way to have it where make run some_stuff_inputted_by_user some_arguments

Comment: like in the custom example, you can change it to run, and pass arg1=from_user. Or, you could use `%:` as the target name, and process `$@` to get the argument.